# Passing data between two PHP pages

Tags: php, html, forms, post, http-post

I have two pages and the first one 'order.php' is for the user to input data then the second one 'saveOrder.php' is for the save order information in the database. I have completed the order saving process by using POST method to submit form data. But I need to know how can I resend data back to 'order.php' in case saving failed (database error or user input data validation failed). Also order details should not be displayed in the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sessions in order.php and 'saveOrder.php' to handle errors between them.

saveOrder.php

```
<?php
  
session_start();
  
$_SESSION["error"] = "an error occured";  
?>
```

order.php

```
 <?php
      
    session_start();
      
    if(isset($_SESSION["error"]) && $_SESSION["error"] != ''){
        echo 'Error : '. $_SESSION["error"];
        unset($_SESSION["error"]);
    }
    ?>
```

reference : https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-sessions/